# error while backing up oracle database using rman

Tags: oracle, rman

This is how i was trying to backup a database without logging in the oracle 10g database.Can anybody please tell me why am I getting this error and how should I try to solve it?

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\sunanda>cd C:\oraclexe

C:\oraclexe>cd app

C:\oraclexe\app>cd oracle

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle>cd product

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product>cd 10.2.0

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0>cd server

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server>cd bin

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>dir rman.exe
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 40EF-0556

Directory of C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN

02/02/2006  12:43 AM         1,552,384 rman.exe
           1 File(s)      1,552,384 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  14,177,832,960 bytes free

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>set ORACLE_SID=demo

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>echo %ORACLE_SID%
demo

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>rman target /
```

After I do this I get the error as below:

```
    Recovery Manager: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Apr 18 14:46:35 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-04005: error from target database:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN>
```

I tried searching about this error but could not understand exactly how to go about it.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dA6BYxF_YE&feature=related. this is the video i referred to while doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You've set the `ORACLE_SID` to `demo` - but there is no such SID. Check what was the SID configured when you installed the database & set to that accordingly.

If you need to find the SID, open the services list ( <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) type `services.msc`. Search for something like `OracleServiceXYZ123`. The characters after `OracleService` will be the SID

Comment: Could you tell me how could I find that out? I searched online but found only how to set the value of ORACLE_SID and not what it should be set to.

Comment: I'm not experienced in rman but I don't see why you need to set it. It'll be set when you install Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Flush your shared pool; it will definitely work.
Try this:

SQL> alter system flush shared_pool;

System altered.